# Including Nests as Separate Entities in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with XSLT for the first time trying to extract some XML data into CSV format. Here's a bit of the input:

```
  <diag>
    <name>A08</name>
    <desc>Viral and other specified intestinal infections</desc>
    <excludes1>
      <note>influenza with involvement of gastrointestinal tract (J09.X3, J10.2, J11.2)</note>
    </excludes1>
    <diag>
      <name>A08.0</name>
      <desc>Rotaviral enteritis</desc>
    </diag>
    <diag>
      <name>A08.1</name>
      <desc>Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk agent and other small round viruses</desc>
      <diag>
        <name>A08.11</name>
        <desc>Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk agent</desc>
        <inclusionTerm>
          <note>Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norovirus</note>
          <note>Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk-like agent</note>
        </inclusionTerm>
      </diag>
      <diag>
        <name>A08.19</name>
        <desc>Acute gastroenteropathy due to other small round viruses</desc>
        <inclusionTerm>
          <note>Acute gastroenteropathy due to small round virus [SRV] NOS</note>
        </inclusionTerm>
      </diag>
    </diag>
    <diag>
      <name>A08.2</name>
      <desc>Adenoviral enteritis</desc>
    </diag>
    <diag>
      <name>A08.3</name>
      <desc>Other viral enteritis</desc>
      <diag>
        <name>A08.31</name>
        <desc>Calicivirus enteritis</desc>
      </diag>
      <diag>
        <name>A08.32</name>
        <desc>Astrovirus enteritis</desc>
      </diag>
      <diag>
        <name>A08.39</name>
        <desc>Other viral enteritis</desc>
        <inclusionTerm>
          <note>Coxsackie virus enteritis</note>
          <note>Echovirus enteritis</note>
          <note>Enterovirus enteritis NEC</note>
          <note>Torovirus enteritis</note>
        </inclusionTerm>
      </diag>
    </diag>
  </diag>
```

The `diag`s are encapsulated in `section`s, which are then under `chapter`s, which are all under a `root`. My desired output would be:

```
A08;Viral and other specified intestinal infections;
A08.0;Rotaviral enteritis;
A08.1;Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk agent and other small round viruses;
A08.11;Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk agent;Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norovirus Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk-like agent
```

Note that any `note`s under an `inclusionTerm` would be concatenated into a single field when exported.

This is the XSLT I'm working with now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="diag">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name" mode="print"/>;<xsl:apply-templates select="desc" mode="print"/>;<xsl:apply-templates select="inclusionTerm/note" mode="print"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works for pulling out root `diag`s (any with a `section` as its parent). I did try adding another `apply-templates` to match the nested `diag`s, but it ended up jumbling each `diag` and all of its `diag` children into a one-line mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an approach like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="';'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//diag"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="diag">
        <xsl:value-of select="name, desc, string-join(inclusionTerm/note, ' ')" separator="{$sep}"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives

```
A08;Viral and other specified intestinal infections;
A08.0;Rotaviral enteritis;
A08.1;Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk agent and other small round viruses;
A08.11;Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk agent;Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norovirus Acute gastroenteropathy due to Norwalk-like agent
A08.19;Acute gastroenteropathy due to other small round viruses;Acute gastroenteropathy due to small round virus [SRV] NOS
A08.2;Adenoviral enteritis;
A08.3;Other viral enteritis;
A08.31;Calicivirus enteritis;
A08.32;Astrovirus enteritis;
A08.39;Other viral enteritis;Coxsackie virus enteritis Echovirus enteritis Enterovirus enteritis NEC Torovirus enteritis
```

Obviously you can adjust the `<xsl:apply-templates select="//diag"/>` if only a certain level of elements should be processed.